# AudioSource in Unity3D does not play WAV file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wav, unity3d-editor

I am updating an AudioSource in Unity3D during runtime when I click.

I created a Cube game object.

When I click the cube I send properties to my AudioSource.

**NOTE:** this is to eventually play many other wav files that are passed in via a string array of pipe delimited wav files (which exist in the Assets Audio folder).

So I need to update the AudioSource with each CLICK EVENT whereby each time it will load a new file selected from the array.

Okay, the Unity3D Editor shows my public variables from the script, and it fills them out at runtime (upon clicking the cube.)

My **path** variable shows up perfectly in the Unity3D editor.

But the problem is although the **Audio Clip** *property* in the editor shows the small orange audio logo (as if something is there/loaded), the name of the file that I grabbed from my Assets/Audio folder is always empty.

Nothing plays, but I get **no errors**!

And the properties *playOnAwake*, *volume*, *etc*. all show me exactly what I express them to do via my script.

**NOTE:** In the first image, the **path** *variable* correctly points to the .wav file.

Why is my .wav not playing?

Why is the .wav filename not appearing in the **Audio Clip** text box area?

[image: My publicly declared variables in the script.]

[image: My created Audio Source.]

```
public Color clickColor;
public Color releaseColor;
public int clickcount = 0;    
public WWW www;
public AudioClip myAudioClip;
public string path;

void CubeClicked(GameObject tmpGameObject)
{
    // CLICK COUNT
    clickcount++;

    // CLICK COLOR
    tmpGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color = clickColor; 

    // IS TRIGGER
    tmpGameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true; 

    //AUDIO
    path = "file://" + Application.dataPath.Substring(0, Application.dataPath.LastIndexOf("/")) + "/Assets/Audio/JetEngine.wav";
    www = new WWW(path);
    myAudioClip = www.audioClip;

    tmpGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myAudioClip;
    tmpGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().playOnAwake = false;
    tmpGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0.999f;
    tmpGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

}
```

Comment: did you checked the audio listner ?

Comment: try doing this : yield return www; after the new WWW(). Also check that your volume is enabled.

Comment: Cabbra your advice put me on the right track.  It works now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cabbra's suggestion was what I needed.  Adding "yield return www;" forced me to use the IEnumerator and magically, it started to work!

```
StartCoroutine(playMusic(tmpGameObject));  

public IEnumerator playMusic(GameObject tmpGameObject){
    /*Same code from before goes here!*/
}
```

Comment: You can't because he *commented* in stead of posting an answer. Answering your own question is fine, you can accept it after 48 hours.

Comment: Luckily, there is very little magic involved. WWW is a background task. If you ask for audioClip straight away it simply hasn't downloaded it yet, so you effectively set the clip of the AudioSource to null.  You have to wait for it to finish.